# tp-link wirless n, TL-WN725N

Tags: wireless, drivers, adapter

I've just bought the above adapter after my old Belkin one gave up. I've seen a few solutions to peoples problems on here but haven't had any success myself yet. Which means this is coming from my phone. Not good.

The adapter doesn't seem to be working at all, the only time I can see it is lsusb- id 0bda:8179 realtek semiconductor corp. Is this what the adapter is meant to look like?

Running 10.04, kernel 2.6.32-45. I've tried installing the rtl8721 drivers, which comes up with 2 errors when I try to install it. Something to do with linux header package, but I'm pretty sure I've got them for my kernel. Tried blacklisting a few drivers but nothing's working. Will upgrading to the latest release be the quickest solution?

Sorry I can't copy more info across, as I said, working off my phone for now!

Thanks for any help

Tim

Answer (score 2):

I was just trying the same, it seems that the Realtek drivers are not compatible with new linux Kernels e.g. Ubuntu 13.04

Yes, Tim Phillips has produced a great solution to this problem. See this thread
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2092934&page=2&highlight=8188CUs

Tim has made available a .deb file that fixes the 13.04 installation bug and included a dkms fix so it's no longer necessary to recompile after each kernel upgrade. Here's a link to the .deb file: https://code.google.com/p/realtek-8188cus-wireless-drivers-3444749-ubuntu-1304/

Answer (score 0):

You might have the same problem I just had solved for me. I'm running peppermint OS 3 (Lubuntu fork with a bit of Mint) so I assume it's comparable.

Basically TPLINK changed the chipset in the WN725N at some point so the old drivers don't work and the new ones aren't included in the kernel yet.

WN725N, version 2 identified as: Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. on my laptop which needs RTL8188EU instead of rtl8721

A very kind forum poster gave me a list of terminal commands to download and install the right packages here:

http://peppermintos.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=5619

It worked perfectly for me after that. I should say that I'm a total newb so don't take this as gospel.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked in my case:

```
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.5-utopic/linux-headers-3.14.5-031405-generic_3.14.5-031405.201405311735_i386.deb
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.5-utopic/linux-image-3.14.5-031405-generic_3.14.5-031405.201405311735_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.14*.deb linux-image-3.14*.deb
sudo update-grub
```

If you have a x64

```
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.5-utopic/linux-headers-3.14.5-031405_3.14.5-031405.201405311735_all.deb
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.5-utopic/linux-headers-3.14.5-031405-generic_3.14.5-031405.201405311735_amd64.deb
wget kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.14.5-utopic/linux-image-3.14.5-031405-generic_3.14.5-031405.201405311735_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-3.14*.deb linux-image-3.14*.deb
sudo update-grub
```